# Basic regex find/replace in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I'm very new to regex, and haven't had luck with properly selecting/replacing these strings because of the special characters involved.

Given a form element like this:

```
<select id="referralForm_currentReferredProducts_1__soldProductId" class="autoWidth soldProductSelect" name="currentReferredProducts[1].soldProductId">
```

How can I select the id and name attributes and increment them? Form elements are being appended to a form as HTML snippets, and I don't have the ability to implement them until they are attached to the DOM.

Thanks!

**Update:**
I've tried using [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) to test different expressions, this one selects the underscores correctly:
`\_[0-9]+\_`

It just isn't actually replacing anything.. here is my code:

```
$.each($('#add-a-product-wrapper').children().last().find('[id*="__"]'), function(){
    $(this).attr('id').replace(/\_[0-9]+\_/, '_'+ replaceIndex +'_');
});
```

Comment: `Form elements are being appended to a form as HTML snippets` You can always use `$(htmlCode)` to parse the HTML and work on it.

Comment: Sorry, never realized that! I've gone back and given credit where credit was due before.

Comment: use data attributes to this kind of thing.

Comment: @nhahtdh agree...Joshua Longanecker that is very decent of you..but yes no doubt you should accept only those answers that really helped you..;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out..

```
$.each($('#add-a-product-wrapper').children().last().find('[id*="__"]'), function(){
    var newVal = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\_[0-9]+\_/g, '_'+ replaceIndex +'_');
    $(this).attr('id', newVal);
});
```

What I didn't realize is that replace() **returns** a value, instead of setting something directly. once a value is returned, it can be set as the new ID of the form element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select').attr('id','new_id').attr('name','new_name');
```

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is that there are a variety of possible form elements that may be added, and I want to have an abstracted way of dealing with them. The only consistent pieces of information I have to work with are the characters wrapped around the incrementing number of a form element: _number__ and [number] .